# Cleared all plots, now ggplot2 will not plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been having issues with ggplot2 for a few days. First, when I would try to run different codes, the p value from my previous plot would show up on the new one. This would happen even when I knew they should have different p values and the dots from the plots were visibly different. I then tried to clear all my plots using the "Clear all plots" broom button. Since I've done this, I have not been able to plot anything. The plots don't automatically pull up like they used to and when I call the plot, it doesn't come up because it appears that the plot isn't saved to my directory and isn't a part of my environment. I've tried running older codes that I know work and still haven't been able to produce any plots.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```r
dev.off()
```

and replotting your graph.